# Get Assets Folder and create a Folder in Assets Folder and create a file in create Folder using windows 8

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

```
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyDocument.Txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Hello");
```

The error is:

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the MSDN documentation available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx:

> The app's install directory is a read-only location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then which is the best place to store temporary data.

Comment: The best place to store temporary data is ApplicationData.TemporaryFolder, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder.aspx)